# Back-end in Model-View-Controller, Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model, backend

In the design pattern Model-View-Controller (MVC), is the back-end database a part of the Model layer, or is it separated from the Model?

Furthermore is it arguable to say that a MySQL database is not a part of Model, since it's placed separately from the Java code?

Comment: Take a look at these pictures: http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/69/javaee/ecommerce/design/mvc-diagram.png and http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/MVC_Diagram_3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) defines the model as "*the domain objects or data structures that represent the application's state.*" With this is mind, we can see that although a database isn't strictly part of the codebase, it still represents (holds) data used, and is therefore (at least somewhat) part of the model. It's easier to see this if you try to consider why it wouldn't be part of the Controller or the View (both of which are supposed to work with the Model and not directly on their own.)

Now, like in the pictures @John Doe posted, you'll see that in oder to preserve the MVC structure, you'll need to provide an interface *to* the database *through* the Model.

As an over simplified example you could consider writing something like this:

```
public ModelDatabaseWrapper implements ModelReadWriteInterface {
    public ModelDatabaseWrapper() {
        /* Prepares to use database... */
    }

    public Object getValue(Object someQuery) throws ModelReadException {
        /* Get something from it... */
    }

    public void putData() throws ModelWriteException {
        /* Insert something int to it... */
    }

    private DataBaseHandle db;
}
```

This is only a guideline, but I'd highlight the point of making a generic `interface` for grouping your Model components based on how they're accessed. In a real application one could have many forms of representing data & state beyond just a database, and so by keeping a clean API it would allow the Controller and View more flexibility much easier.

I hope I helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

The database is the persistence, and not really part of the MVC pattern directly (although it is common to persist model state to a database).